# In C#, How can I Rotate the List to the Right by Specified numbers of places?

Tags: c#

I'm try to program a test, where I have two parameters, a List of ints called items, and a single int called places, in which I will rotate the list to the right by the specified number of places.

Here's the what I have attempted so far.

```
 public void Test8(List<int> items, int places)
    {
        int a = 0;

        if (a < items.Count)
        {
            a = a % items.Count;
        }

        int[] result = new int[items.Count];

        for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
        {
            result[i] = items[items.Count - a + i];
        }
        int j = 0;
        for (int i = a; i < items.Count; i++)
        {
            result[i] = items[j];
            j++;
        }
```

Comment: no where in that example do you use the parameter "places"...may help to post the full method

Comment: Meaningful variable names could help you. What is `a`? You initialize it to 0, but then immediately check if it's greater than `items.Count`. Why? It could never occur since `items.Count` can't be less than 0. Where's the `places` parameter used that you mentioned?

Answer (score 1):

You can use LINQ to do this:

```
IEnumerable<T> RotateLeft<T>(IEnumerable<T> list, int places)
{
    return list.Skip(places).Concat(list.Take(places));
}

IEnumerable<T> RotateRight<T>(IEnumerable<T> list, int places)
{
    return RotateLeft(list, list.Count() - places);
}
```